# css negative border shape

Tags: html, css, background, header

I have such image
[image]

this is SVG format. I need to use it as header background (cover) under this element are others what should be visible in the place where a header is rounded.

I can't use it as contain background and as cover because in a different resolution it looks bad.
My idea is to slice this image and uses just left and right sides as before and after.

But maybe someone has a better solution. For example, CSS gradients ad background image. But I did tests for a few and  I can't set such shape as transparent, or fill colour just a part.

EDIT:
I'd like 100% width with static height what looks like this
[image]
Thanks in advance for any hints.

Problem with SVG is that the original size is 300x91 and when I set it to 1980px width than height is too big or curve is invisible.

I can't also set a white rounded layer as before because I need to the transparent background in a place where is the curve.

Comment: I think SVG is generally a good solution for something like this. Maybe you need to elaborate on how and why it looks bad and try to solve that.

Comment: Please show us the result you expect in an image, for example?

Comment: I updated my question. Now there is image what I received from the designer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

div {
  width: 300px;/*for example*/
  margin: 0 auto;/*for example*/
  border-top: 30px solid black;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;/*for example*/
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 25px solid #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

You might need to modify the values as per your requirements.